# How to access prevProps' in React Hooks when prevProps' data type is object or array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My question is this, I'm having an array I need to monitor its change in my componentDidUpdate lifecycle, now I'm trying to rewrite the component in hooks, I'm having issue in doing so in hooks, a lot of the solutions I found on the internet suggests to create a customized usePrevious hook like this

```
    const usePrevious = value => {
      const ref = useRef();
      useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value;
      });
      return ref.current;
    };
```

But I found that this hook can only deal with primitive data type, it doesn't seem to work with object or array...

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!_.isEqual(myArray, prevProps.myArray)) {
      // do something...
    }
  }
```

Comment: it works also with arrays or objects

Answer (score -1):

From what you're saying I think using a `useEffect` hook that has the prop you want to watch for as dependency and the logic inside should do the trick, you can check the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for a more detailed explanation, but basically, it would look like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // code to run when it changes
}, [yourVar]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).